# Apply Arithmetic based on multiple conditions using Googlesheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have headcount data and want to apply arithmetic based on specific team/location.
[Example Table (left) and Conditions (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JxW6.png)

For example, team A in location A has 100 headcount and I want to use googlesheet query to show an additional 50 headcount to only team A in location A.

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMz4h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need query to perform this operation, you will just need a simple combination of [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) and [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) to achieve what you are aiming for.

In the following formula I used `ARRAYFORMULA` to return an array of cells and therefore all the outputs by adding this formula to a single cell. Then I used `IF` with the symbol `*` (which represents the logical operator `AND`) to compare the desired columns and if the conditions were met return the headcount with the added value (and if not just return the previous value).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A4=F2)*(B2:B4=F3) ,C2:C4+F4,C2:C4))
```

[image]

Comment: Understood! But I want to use query because the list of team and locations is dynamic. I don't want to have to drag the formula down everytime a new combination of team and locations emerges.

Comment: I understand now your requirements. I have updated my answer accordingly so that you won't have to drag the formula everytime and so that the formula is dynamic. Let me know if this works well for your case scenario :D